# Is it possible to combine multiple IQueryable into a single one without using Union?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

Good evening. Is it possible to combine multiple `IQueryable` into a single one without using `Union` in `EF Core 2`? The main problem is that it doesn't allow to use methods like `.Union(), .Except()` etc.
It's important that `IQueryable` should be executed as a single query.

This is what I want to get: `toCreateSubquery.Union(toDeleteSubquery)`

The queries I want to combine are listed below.

```
var toCreateSubquery =
    validLinks
        .Where(
            rl => !existingLinks.Any(
                el => el.Contract == rl.Contract && el.Estate == rl.Estate)) // Except() doesn't work'
        .Select(x => new {x.Contract, x.Estate, Type = ActionType.Create});

var toDeleteSubquery =
    existingLinks
        .Where(el => !validLinks.Any(rl => el.Contract == rl.Contract && el.Estate == rl.Estate))
        .Select(x => new {x.Contract, x.Estate, Type = ActionType.Delete});
```

[This is the visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxLyY.png) of the problem I'm solving.

I want to get the union of these sets without intersection and be able to distinguish belonging to one of these sets.

Just in case, I attach the code of getting these sets:

```
var validLinks = from ac in _context.AreaContracts
                from e in _context.Estate
                where (from al in e.AreaLinks select al.Area.Id).Contains(ac.Area.Id) ||
                      e.Geometry.Intersects(
                          ac.Area.Geometry)
                select new { Contract = ac.Contract.Id, Estate = e.Id };

var existingLinks = from sd in _context.SquareDistributions
    select new { Contract = sd.Contract.Id, Estate = sd.Estate.Id };
```

Thank you for your attention.